# LocalStorage strategy for user and message data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I am looking for a simple strategy to store user data, as well as messages. I was thinking of using different key values like some random token (**Ynjk_nkjSNKJN**) for users and some real ids (1,2,3) for messages.

Has anyone ever had that problem?

The reason is that I would like to keep `localStorage` always up to date with new messages from the server, but users should not be deleted during an update.

Thanks

Comment: The user's ID, message ID (and content, if you want it to be readable offline), and a server-generated message timestamp would give you enough information to deal with disconnects, reconnects, messages being sent out of order, etc.

Another consideration to make is to have "conversations" rather than messages from users. Then you'd need a conversation ID, message ID (& content), userID, and the timestamp but you'd avoid annoyances later down the line (such as group conversations).

Comment: Thanks Adam, I guess I'll do that. I guess localStorage is just what it is :) and not a localDB.

Comment: Yeah, any implementation is going to need to initially linearly read through whatever value (usually JSON) has been stored at each key. You might be able to use `user`/`conversation` IDs as localStorage keys but, ultimately, you're dealing with a key-value store rather than a full DB engine--although I'm sure there are javascript databases you can run in the client that use localStorage to store their structure if you *desperately* need that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle "tables" in `localStorage` this way:

```
//columns should be an array of column literals
function createTable(tableName, columns) {
    db[tableName] = {rows: {}, columns: columns};
}

function insertInto(tableName, row, id) {
    var newRow = {};
    for (var columnName in row) {
        if (db[tableName].columns.indexOf(columnName) === -1) {
            //invalid column
            return false;
        }
        newRow[columnName] = row[columnName];
    }
    db[tableName].rows[id] = newRow;
    return true;
}

function getIDs(tableName, where) {
    var IDs = [];
    for (var id in db[tableName].rows) {
        if (where(db[tableName].rows[id])) {
            IDs[IDs.length]=id;
        }
    }
    return IDs;
}

function update(tableName, where, what) {
    what(tableName, getIDs(tableName, where));
}

function deleteRecord(tableName, where) {
    var removeIDs = getIDs(tableName, where);
    for (var id in removeIDs) {
        //Could be done by regexes, but I am not fluent with them and I am lazy to check them out
        delete db[tableName].rows[removeIDs[id]];
    }
}

function select(tableName, where) {
    var IDs = getIDs(tableName, where);
    var result = {};
    for (var id in db[tableName].rows) {
        result[id] = db[tableName].rows[id];
    }
    return result;
}

function dropTable(tableName) {
    delete db[tableName];
}
```

You probably see that this is only a minimalistic implementation, but with the same approach you can implement altering, joins, grouping and so on. My focus here was just to illustrate how you can create a database. Let's go to the next step, storing the database into `localStorage`:

```
localStorage.setItem("db", JSON.stringify(db));
```

You will need to be able to convert back the local storage item to object, especially because you want to reuse your database even after reload. Let's see how you should initialize `db`:

```
var db = !!localStorage.getItem("db") ? angular.fromJson(localStorage.getItem("db")) : {};
```

Comment: Oh, nice. I will take a look at it! Thank you very much!

Comment: @MichelH, you are welcome. If this answers your question, then you might consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Localstorage is a key-value store, which stores everything in `string` format. So, the messages will be identified by one key (e.g. "messages") and the users another key (e.g. "users").

Then you need to create 2 (angular) services one for the messages and one for the users. Both will interface with localstorage (using the respective keys) and will perform the operations that you want.

If you provide us with more information then we could help you a bit more.

Comment: Thank you ipinak, I've implemented all of it. I guess I was hoping for an answer that turns localStorage into a usable db but I guess that is not what localStorage was meant to be.